# Fortnite stuck before showing intro video

Tags: technical-issues, fortnite-battle-royale

After updating to v17 today I'm having some problems. I can start the game, but after selecting "Battle Royale" the screen goes black with a spinner that just keep spinning. If I move the mouse I get an arrow in the bottom right corner but clicking it does nothing. After 30 minutes like that I killed the process. I guess I'm supposed to watch the new intro video but the screen is black and just showing the spinner.

I've tried to reinstall the game. I'm running it in compatibility Windows 8 mode with disabled fullscreen effects and I've added the DirectX 11 argument to the launcher in Epic Launcher client.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/jgzpv1/comment/g9uef95/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) post suggests trying to enter Creative Mode instead of Battle Royale, and then exit and try again.